# Conversion of Generic using Interfaces

Tags: c#, generics

I'm dealing with a code base that makes generous use of Generics with class types. I've been pushing to use interfaces (for a variety of reasons). In my work of slowly converting things, I've hit the following and I can't get past it.

Put simply (and minimally), the problem I'm facing is the following:

```
private static IList<IDictionary<int, string>> exampleFunc()
{
    //The following produces a compile error of:
    // Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,string>>' to 
    //  'System.Collections.Generic.IList<System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<int,string>>'. 
    // An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)  
    return new List<Dictionary<int, string>>(); 
}
```

As it says in the comment, it produces a compile time error.

How can I produce an object that adheres to the interface that can be returned?

In general, how can I convert or cast the "inner" type?

---

**Update**: My example may be misleading. My situation is not specific to a List that contains Dictionary elements.  There are instances of that but it could also just as well be `IList<IVehicle> vehicleList = new List<Car>();`

The crux of my question is how to deal with mis-matched Generic Types.

Comment: Why not simply `new List<IDictionary<int, string>>()`?

Comment: @Jon Presumably he got the list from somewhere else, or is actually constructing/populating/doing other stuff with the list here, and just put what he did as it's a minimal reproducible example of the problem.

Comment: @Servy: That's why I asked instead of answering directly.

Comment: @Jon, the source is considered "done" and therefore doesn't get updated (let alone tested) much. Drastic changes to the source aren't possible for the the time being but meanwhile consumers (under very active development) are stuck using concrete classes causing poor design decisions / practices.

Comment: @FrankV: Well, it can't be considered done if it doesn't compile. So either this particular piece is not done, or else the question doesn't accurately describe the problem? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Jon, the original source of the data is done, not the assembly that won't build at the moment.

Comment: Your update example doesn't make a difference, `IList<T>` is still invariant on `T`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a method to work through my interface conversions. Here's the situation again, falling back to my *example* of a List of Dictionaries. (Could be any data types -- built in or custom though).

```
class Program
{
    private static List<Dictionary<string, Guid>> GetList()
    {
        var myList = new List<Dictionary<string, Guid>>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            var newDict = new Dictionary<string, Guid>();
            for (var j = 0; j < 25; j++)
            {
                newDict.Add(j.ToString(), Guid.NewGuid());
            }
            myList.Add(newDict);
        }
        return myList;
    }
    //Really, I want the following to use interfaces; lets not worry about why there is a middle-man function.
    private static IList<Dictionary<string, Guid>> MyIntermediateFuncForAReason() 
    {
        var originalList = GetList();
        //whatever processing.
        return originalList;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = MyIntermediateFuncForAReason();
        // whatever...
    }
}
```

Modify the `MyIntermediateFuncForAReason` to convert the to the desired types such as:

```
private static IList<IDictionary<string, Guid>> MyIntermediateFuncForAReason()
{
    var originalList = GetList();
    //whatever processing.
    return originalList.Select((IDictionary<string, Guid> i) => i).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code won't work because `IList<T>` is not [covariant/contravariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you create the list yourself, you can give it a compatible type to start with:

```
private static IList<IDictionary<int, string>> exampleFunc()
{
    var list = new List<IDictionary<int, string>>();
    list.Add(new Dictionary<int, string>());
    return list;
}
```

If that's not an option, e.g. because you get it like that from an external source, you can cast it.

```
private static IList<IDictionary<int, string>> exampleFunc()
{
    var list = new List<Dictionary<int, string>>();
    list.Add(new Dictionary<int, string>());
    return list.Cast<IDictionary<int, string>>().ToList();
}
```

Comment: This is simply a worse way of creating a list of `IDictionary` in the first place. And nothing to do with variance.

Comment: @Jon Well this one is for the more general case where the list isn't empty

Comment: Much better after adding the 2nd example. I would not even show the first version, it is trying to show a Anti-Patern.

Comment: @BenAaronson: Irrelevant, as the second example shows.

Comment: @BenAaronson Your first example creates 2 Lists in memory and must copy the content from one list to another and perform a `Cast` operation on each member of the list. The 2nd does none of that. I think that is what Jon was trying to get at about being "a worse way".

Comment: I've swapped the examples, as suggested.

Comment: @Jon You're making  assumptions about the OP's requirements though. The question says: "In general, how can I convert or cast the "inner" type?" I would think "in general" would include cases where the starting list is a type you don't have control over

Comment: @BenAaronson: Where am I making this assumption?

Comment: @Jon Well perhaps I misunderstood you, but that's a case where you'd have to use the (now) second example

Comment: @Jon I also don't understand what you mean when you say it has nothing to do with variance. If you replaced `IList` with `IEnumerable` in the OP's code, it would work.

Comment: @BenAaronson: Turns out that was nothing other than a mistake on my part due to not being careful enough. Please disregard it.

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to treat an `IList` as if it were covariant, meaning that you want to be able to treat all instances of the generic argument as if they are in fact of a less derived type.  That won't work because `IList` is *invariant*.  (Imagine what would happen if someone added a `SomeOtherTypeOfDictionary<int,string>` to the list that you return.  You've now put something that's not a `Dictionary<int,string>` into a `List<Dictionary<int, string>>`.

You could return an `IEnumerable<Dictionary<int, string>>` which *is* covariant.

Or, if you don't actually have an already populated list, just create a list of the appropriate type (`List<IDictionary<int, string>>`) from the start.

Another option is to create a *new* list and copy over all of the elements in it `return new List<Dictionary<int, string>>().Cast<IDictionary<int, string>>>().ToList();`, although this *usually* isn't good design, particularly of you haven't already populated the list with data.

And all of this assumes that you have a real compelling reason to have an `IList<IDictionary<int,string>>` to begin with.  I'd assert that there really isn't a compelling reason to restrict your `List` and `Dictionary` to the corresponding interfaces in the first place, and that there's nothing wrong with returning a `List<Dictionary<int,string>>` unless you really do have use cases for returning non-List ILists or non-Dictionary IDictionaries.  It complicates your code, removes valuable functionality for the caller, and doesn't really add value if you aren't going to ever return different implementations of that interface.

Comment: I'm not really dealing with an List<Dictionary<...>> that is just an example. The types vary depending but it all boils down to the T being some class and I desire it to be an interface.

Comment: @FrankV If that last paragraph doesn't apply to you then that's fine; the rest of the answer still addresses the case here, which is that you can either ensure that your interface is covariant, allowing your code to work, or you won't be able to simply cast the type, as its wouldn't maintain type safety to do so, and you'll need to create a new type.

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>` implements `IList<T>`, as we all know.  Therefore, we can write this:

```
IList<int> xs = new List<int>();
```

Now assume an interface `I` and a class `C`, where `C` implements `I`.  We can write this:

```
I x = new C();
```

It is a common mistake to combine these two facts into a belief that this should be possible:

```
IList<I> xs = new List<C>();
```

Why is this illegal?  Two reasons:

First, `List<C>` does not implement `IList<I>`.  It implements `IList<C>`.

Second, treating a `List<C>` as an `IList<I>` breaks type safety.  For example, consider class `D`, which also implements interface `I`.  If we could assign a `List<C>` to `IList<I>`, then we could do this:

```
IList<C> cs = new List<C>();
IList<I> eyes = cs;  //hypothetically legal for this thought experiment
eyes.Add(new D());   //legal because D implements I
C c = cs[0];         //legal, but results in a C variable pointing to a D object!
```

To prevent this, the compiler disallows the second line of code.

If this were legal, then the `List<T>.Add(T)` method would have to check the type of its argument, which negates one of the primary benefits of the generic system in the first place.

The solution to your problem is to use concrete collection types instantiated with interface type arguments:

```
private static IList<I> exampleFunc()
{
    return new List<I>();
}
```

If you're getting the list from elsewhere, you have two choices:

1. Write a wrapper class that implements `IList<I>` but holds a reference to the `IList<C>`, casting objects (possibly raising exceptions) before adding them to the inner list.
2. Copy the data into a `List<I>`.

The only reason to use the first solution, which is a bit cumbersome, is if you need changes to the list to be reflected in some other part of the application that has a reference to the original `List<C>`.

As other posters have mentioned, this question is related to the concept of generic type parameter covariance and contravariance, which allows you to write `IEnumerable<I> xs = new List<C>();` because `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant in T.  If you want to understand this better, and why `List<T>` can't be covariant in T, you might want to start with Eric Lippert's excellent series on the subject, starting with http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx